# Looking for a Maven Repository Cleanup script (unix) for Snapshot builds (diskspace)

Tags: bash, maven-2, continuous-integration, cron, snapshot

So we have our own private Maven repository that we publish snapshot builds to.

We have lots builds so diskspace is starting to become a problem for all our snapshot builds. While its fun and all to go manually do this I was wondering if anyone knows of a CRON script that I can run to do the snapshot cleanup.

I know sonatype does this for their own repo but I could not find a script.

Answer (score 3):

To find all snapshot files that were updated more than two weeks ago:

```
 find . -type f -mtime +14 | grep SNAPSHOT
```

Pipe that to `xargs rm` and you should be good.

The one caveat: a repository manager will create a `metadata.xml` file that lists all published revisions. Assuming that you're just using `scp` to publish, and a webserver to retrieve, I don't think that file exists (so the fact that this script doesn't touch it shouldn't be an issue).

Comment: BTW, having used the free version of Nexus, I don't think I'd ever go back to a simple repository ... in fact, I run it on my home machine.

Comment: The problem with this is that it will delete the last version of snapshots that are more than 2 weeks old (or however long you choose.) Trying to figure out a way to get it to leave the last version alone.

Answer (score 1):

The following script works fine for me:

```
#!/bin/sh
REPO=/var/www/maven2/snapshots
find $REPO -type d -name '*-SNAPSHOT' | while read project; do
    if [ -f $project/maven-metadata.xml ]; then # Make sure this is a maven artifact directory
            # Assume that snapshot numbering is designed to be sorted numerically
            latestversion=$(ls $project | grep -v 'maven-metadata.*' | sort -n | grep '\.pom$' | tail -n1)
            latestversion=$(basename $latestversion .pom)
            # Delete everything, but the latest version and the maven metadata
            find $project -type f | grep -v -e 'maven-metadata.*' -e "$latestversion.*" | xargs rm
    fi
done
```